# Zeros of model partition function (Statistical physics). Example

Tags: complex-analysis

I am interested in the location and density of zeros (qualitative behavior) of the following simple partition function:
$$Z_N(z)= \sum_{n=0}^N g(n, N)z^n , $$
 where  $g(n, N)=e^{(n-\rho n^2/N)}$,   $\rho \geq0$,  is the constant  as $N$ tends to infinity,$z=e^{-\beta  \varepsilon}$, $\beta$ is complex reversed temperature,  $\varepsilon=const > 0$

Has the answer  something to do with the properties of the *Jacobi theta function*?